# What are the molecular orbitals of the hypothetical linear H₃⁺ molecule?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

> What would be the wave function of the lowest energy molecular orbital of a hypothetical linear $\ce{H3+}$ molecule?

According to the LCAO method, I feel the lowest energy MO will be $\mathrm{1s(A) + 1s(B) + 1s(C)}$, where e.g. $\mathrm{1s(A)}$ is the wave function of the $\mathrm{1s}$ orbital of one of the Hydrogen atoms. This has $0$ nodes and has the lowest energy.

Isn't this correct?

Comment: Why are you asking about hypothetical linear H₃⁺ molecule, when there is real [triangular H₃⁺](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trihydrogen_cation)?

Comment: @Mithoron I can't change my homework question, can I ? 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lowest energy MO is : $\psi_1 = (1/2)(\phi_A+ \sqrt2\phi_B+\phi_C)$.

Then comes the MO: $\psi_2 = (1/\sqrt2)(\phi_A- \phi_C)$.

The highest energy MO is  $\psi_3 = (1/2)(-\phi_A+ \sqrt2\phi_B-\phi_C)$.

Where  $\phi$ denotes the atomic orbital $1s$ on each hydrogen atom. $A$, $B$ and  $C$ denote hydrogen atoms, where  $B$ is the central one.